# How to get my listener to work with Spigot Plugin?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

Recently, I coded this plugin that would open up an inventory when you clicked on a player, but for some reason, the inventory isn't opening.

Main:

```
package me.jacobsscoots.main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.PlayerInventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import me.jacobsscoots.listeners.Admin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin{

Admin admin;

List<String> toggle = new ArrayList<String>();

public void onEnable() {
    getLogger().info("Utils is now enabled");
    admin = new Admin();
    Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(admin, this);
}

public void onDisable() {
    getLogger().info("Utils is now disabled");
}

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
    Player player = (Player) sender;
    PlayerInventory pi = player.getInventory();
    if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("admin")){
        if(!(sender instanceof Player)){
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Staff Mode" + ChatColor.WHITE + " >> " + ChatColor.GRAY + "You muse be a player to use this command!");
            return false;
        }
        if(toggle.contains(player.getName())){
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Staff Mode" + ChatColor.WHITE + " >> " + ChatColor.GRAY + "You are no longer in staff mode.");
            toggle.remove(player.getName());

            pi.clear();

            return true;
        }

        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Staff Mode" + ChatColor.WHITE + " >> " + ChatColor.GRAY + "You are now in staff mode.");
        toggle.add(player.getName());


        ItemStack paper = new ItemStack(Material.PAPER, 1);
        ItemMeta meta = paper.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "Punish");
        paper.setItemMeta(meta);

        pi.addItem(paper);

        admin.setEnabled(true);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Listener class:

```
package me.jacobsscoots.listeners;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.EventPriority;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEntityEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;

import net.md_5.bungee.api.ChatColor;

public class Admin implements Listener{

private boolean enabled = false;

@EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.HIGHEST, ignoreCancelled = true)
public void onAdminEvent(PlayerInteractEntityEvent e) {
    if (!(e.getRightClicked() instanceof Player))
        return;

    if(enabled == false){
        return;
    }
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    Player target = (Player) e.getRightClicked();

    if(p.isOp() && p.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().equals(Material.PAPER) && e.getRightClicked().getType() == EntityType.PLAYER){
        openGUI(p, target);
    }
}



@EventHandler
public void onInventoryClick(InventoryClickEvent event)
{
    if (event.isCancelled())
        return;

    if (!event.getInventory().getName().contains(" Punishment"))
        return;

    Player player = (Player) event.getWhoClicked();
    Player target = Bukkit.getPlayer(ChatColor.stripColor(event.getClickedInventory().getName().split(" ")[0]));
    ItemStack item = event.getCurrentItem();
    Integer slot = event.getSlot();

    if (item == null || item.getType() == Material.AIR || !item.hasItemMeta())
        return;

    if (slot == 20){
        target.kickPlayer(player.getName() + " Banned you for: " + item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName());
    }
    event.setCancelled(true);
}

private void openGUI(Player player, Player target) {

    Inventory inv = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 54, ChatColor.GRAY + target.getName() + " Punishment");

    ItemStack Ban_1 = new ItemStack(Material.IRON_BARDING, 1);
    ItemMeta BanMeta_1 = Ban_1.getItemMeta();
    BanMeta_1.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "Hacked Clients, Cheats and Exploits");
    Ban_1.setItemMeta(BanMeta_1);

    ItemStack Ban_2 = new ItemStack(Material.IRON_BARDING, 1);
    ItemMeta BanMeta_2 = Ban_2.getItemMeta();
    BanMeta_2.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "Spamming/Advertising");
    Ban_2.setItemMeta(BanMeta_2);

    ItemStack Ban_3 = new ItemStack(Material.IRON_BARDING, 1);
    ItemMeta BanMeta_3 = Ban_3.getItemMeta();
    BanMeta_3.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "Not Respecting Players or Staff Members");
    Ban_3.setItemMeta(BanMeta_3);

    ItemStack Ban_4 = new ItemStack(Material.IRON_BARDING, 1);
    ItemMeta BanMeta_4 = Ban_4.getItemMeta();
    BanMeta_4.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "DDOS/Dox Jokes and Threats");
    Ban_4.setItemMeta(BanMeta_4);

    ItemStack Ban_5 = new ItemStack(Material.IRON_BARDING, 1);
    ItemMeta BanMeta_5 = Ban_5.getItemMeta();
    BanMeta_5.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "Mods that provide unfair advantages");
    Ban_5.setItemMeta(BanMeta_5);

    ItemStack Ban_6 = new ItemStack(Material.IRON_BARDING, 1);
    ItemMeta BanMeta_6 = Ban_6.getItemMeta();
    BanMeta_6.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "Racism and Sexism");
    Ban_6.setItemMeta(BanMeta_6);

    ItemStack Ban_7 = new ItemStack(Material.IRON_BARDING, 1);
    ItemMeta BanMeta_7 = Ban_7.getItemMeta();
    BanMeta_7.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "False Reporting");
    Ban_7.setItemMeta(BanMeta_7);

    ItemStack Ban_8 = new ItemStack(Material.IRON_BARDING, 1);
    ItemMeta BanMeta_8 = Ban_8.getItemMeta();
    BanMeta_8.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "Greifing/Block Spam");
    Ban_8.setItemMeta(BanMeta_8);

    ItemStack Pane_1 = new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, (short) 11);

    ItemStack Pane_2 = new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, (short) 14);
    ItemMeta PaneMeta_2 = Pane_2.getItemMeta();
    PaneMeta_2.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "Kick");
    Pane_2.setItemMeta(PaneMeta_2);

    ItemStack Pane_3 = new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, (short) 10);
    ItemMeta PaneMeta_3 = Pane_3.getItemMeta();
    PaneMeta_3.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GREEN + "Warn");
    Pane_3.setItemMeta(PaneMeta_3);

    ItemStack Exit = new ItemStack(Material.BARRIER, 1, (short) 10);
    ItemMeta ExitMeta = Exit.getItemMeta();
    ExitMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "Exit GUI");
    Exit.setItemMeta(ExitMeta);

    ItemStack skull = new ItemStack(Material.SKULL_ITEM, 1, (short) 3);

    inv.setItem(0, Pane_1);
    inv.setItem(1, Pane_1);
    inv.setItem(2, Pane_1);
    inv.setItem(3, Pane_2);
    inv.setItem(4, skull);
    inv.setItem(5, Pane_2);
    inv.setItem(6, Pane_1);
    inv.setItem(7, Pane_1);
    inv.setItem(8, Pane_1);
    inv.setItem(20, Ban_1);
    inv.setItem(21, Ban_2);
    inv.setItem(22, Ban_3);
    inv.setItem(23, Ban_4);
    inv.setItem(24, Ban_5);
    inv.setItem(30, Ban_6);
    inv.setItem(31, Ban_7);
    inv.setItem(32, Ban_8);
    inv.setItem(45, Pane_1);
    inv.setItem(46, Pane_1);
    inv.setItem(47, Pane_1);
    inv.setItem(48, Pane_3);
    inv.setItem(49, Exit);
    inv.setItem(50, Pane_3);
    inv.setItem(51, Pane_1);
    inv.setItem(52, Pane_1);
    inv.setItem(53, Pane_1);

    player.openInventory(inv);
}

public boolean isEnabled(){
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled){
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
}
```

Plugin.yml:

```
name: Utils
version: 1.4.1
description: Staff mode plugin for servers
author: SickNation
main: me.jacobsscoots.main.Main
database: false
commands:
admin:
description: Default toggle command for staff mode.
usage: Syntax error! Simply type /&lt;command&gt; to go into staff mode.
```

Comment: Naming conventions, please! `banMeta2`, not `BanMeta_2`!

Answer (score 3):

The comparison in the last statement of the `PlayerInteractEntityEvent` method:

```
p.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().equals(Material.PAPER)
```

will always be `false`, because `getItemInMainHand()` returns an `ItemStack`, `Material.PAPER` is an enumerator and the `equals` method in the `ItemStack` interface contains the line:

```
if (!(obj instanceof ItemStack)) {
    return false;
}
```

I'm guessing you meant to write

```
getItemInMainHand().getType().equals(Material.PAPER)
```

... comparing two `Material` enumerators. When I tested your code and changed that line, the GUI opened.